# how to create a custom statement

Tags: c#, function, c#-4.0, operator-overloading

Is it possible to write your own conditional statements or overload current ones?

what i actually want to do is

```
object obj = null;

if(obj) // or something like if(1==1 || obj && obj.Value)
    // do something
else
    // do someotherstuff
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly, but for the specific case you mentioned, you can overload how to evaluate an instance of a specific class to `true`/`false`:

```
// returns true if the object evaluates to true
public static bool operator true(YourClass x)
{
    return x != null;
}

// returns true if the object evaluates to false
public static bool operator false(YourClass x) 
{
    return x == null;
}
```

That way, you could do this:

```
YourClass x = new YourClass();

if (x) // same as "if (x != null)" (defined in operator true)
    // do something
else if (!x) // same as "if (x == null)" (defined in operator false)
    // do someotherstuff
```

More info:
[true Operator (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x6y6z4d.aspx)
[false Operator (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6292hy1k.aspx)

Comment: +1 for your nice solution but unfortunately not the answer to my question if there is a way or maybe no way to create a custom statement

Comment: @WiiMaxx What i meant by "Not exactly" was you can't overload the conditional statements such as `if`, `else` or create new ones. You can only overload the operators, such as `||` or `&&`. What would you want to redefine `if` to do anyway?

Comment: if was just an example there was no actual need behind this question. I cam across some forum where people asked about this but one of them got an answer, also sometimes it nerves to write `if(value != null)` so i thought it would be an good example

Comment: @WiiMaxx That's exactly what `operator true` and `operator false` do. If you just return the result of a `null` check in their implementation, you can write `if (value)`. That doesn't change anything about the if-statement, it just changes the interpretation of `value`.